# Allow User to Save Generated Array String for Later Viewing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm creating a small app that generates baby names from 2 separate NSArrays. I have 1 setup for first name and 1 setup for middle name. When the button is pushed it concatenates 2 NSStrings at random as seen with this code:

```
int a = arc4random() % 2;
int b = arc4random() % 2;


// populate the array for the names
NSArray *firstNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Anna", 
@"Amy", 
@"Amber",  nil];
NSArray *middleNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Brenda", @"Beatrix", nil];

// concatenate strings at index of array
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [firstNameArray objectAtIndex:a], [middleNameArray objectAtIndex:b]];

// display the newly created first & middle names

babyname.text = fullName;
```

I'm kind of at a loss for how to allow a user to 'favorite' a particular name and save it to a new view (probably table view). Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would probably want to do is store the names selected so that you could refer to them later. You may wish to create a Person class or something of the like and have a property in it called favorite which is a BOOL value. Then you would just have to set the favorite property to YES for the ones the user wants to favorite.

A good mechanism to store a custom class and have it persist is Core Data, but it really depends on how many Person instances you will/could have. Core Data is really easy to implement once you get the hang of it and there are many tuorials online of how to use it. I would check out the iTunesU videos from Stanford on CoreData using UIDocument and UIManagedDocument. I found them very helpful.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have given a snippet of your code from which the exact flow of your logic in your program is incomprehensible , assuming that u have a textfield for user to input and a button to mark it as favorite then in the action of button you can get the text from textfield and store it in some array .Moreover you don't store data in tableview but you display it there.You can then use the Favorited array to display the names in a tableview .

You can use NSUserDefaults,plist,sqlite,coredata for persistent storage.
NSUserDefaults and plist can handle only low amount data efficiently.

Please See My Link on 
[persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534479/936588)

[Tutorial on TableView](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/)

Comment: Your assumption of the logic is correct, a UILabel displays the text and there is a button next to it that says "favorite".